# Is there a reason why probability density is written as $\psi^*\psi$ instead of $\psi\psi^*$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

As the title states, I see $|\psi|^2$ written as $\psi^*\psi$ instead of $\psi\psi^*$. Are both correct or is there a reason behind it? As far as I'm aware, the only time I see this sort of ordering being important is when ordering two operators.

Comment: $\psi^*\psi$ is the product of $\psi$ with its complex conjugate. That product is commutative, so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Gert Thank you so much, all the sources I check on the web shows it as the complex conjugate coming first. So it's merely a convention?

Comment: It's just a bit clearer, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, so it looks like more general inner products. For example, if you have two real vectors $v$ and $w$, their dot product $v \cdot w$ can also be written as $v^Tw$ where the $T$ means 'transpose'. Similarly if the vectors are complex the inner product is $v^\dagger w$.

In general, you can either think of the dot product as an operation that takes two vectors and spits out a number ($v \cdot w$), or as the result of a row vector/"dual vector" ($v^T$) acting on a column vector ($w$). Note that order does matter here; even though $v \cdot w = w \cdot v$, $wv^T$ is not $v^T w$.

The $\psi^*\psi$ notation is the same. It happens to not be necessary in this case, though it is necessary in general; once you move onto Dirac notation, you'll want $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle$ and not $|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$, and if you take the product of two different wavefunctions it matters which is conjugated.

Comment: Thank you! I learnt a bit of Dirac notation some time back and was wondering if it's because of that. I'm revising QM in preparation for undergraduate study so your reminder on inner products was also very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other answers, in principle the order does not matter. However, it does matter once you evaluate certain operators such as differential operators, since e.g.
$$
\int \psi^*(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x)
$$
is different from
$$
\int \psi(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi^*(x)\ .
$$
For this reason, $\psi^*$ is generally placed on the very left and $\psi$ on the very right, even in cases where the order does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It makes sense now that I look at the part on the momentum operator.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially evaluating a inner/dot product in a particular basis. So, the order doesn't matter for the same function dotted with itself. But if you choose two different functions and want to calculate their dot product density, you'll have a difference, namely why (a+ib)(c-id)$\neq$(c+id)(a-ib), because unless both complex numbers are the same, you won't get the same value always.

So, yes the order definitely matters. It looks prettier too :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, now that the inner product is mentioned, I have another question. Even if they are the same function, wouldn't the order also matter?  If psi isn't a square matrix, psi*psi would give a different result from psipsi*

Comment: @Complimentarity The psi's are thought of as column vectors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason, because it's obviously commutative. Personally, I guess it looks nicer that way.